# How to pass Current logged in User to BCS Entity

Tags: 2010

we are in planning for Converting ASP.NET application in SharePoint 2010 and this application use forms based authentication using Sql Membership provider.First thing here is we can not get rid of existing database and convert it to SharePoint list as this database is used by other application in organization so i am thinking of Configure SharePoint site using forms based authentication and use BCS to get data from there Backend Sql database.

Now i want to pass current logged user(FBA) to BCS entity to get data based on current user.is this possible ? if yes please advise

Thanks 
Ronak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer and i am sharing it so it will be useful for others as well.In BCS you can create filter for each method with type UserContext and that will pass logged in User identity to method.

Thanks 
ROnak